# Wrap long text file but save first X characters for each line

Tags: bash, shell, powershell

I have a text note file that I need to break up into 200 character lines. But, I need to keep the first 50 characters from the original line as it allows the note file to import into clients system. I have been playing with bash and found `fold -50` will fold it at 50 characters and then `fold -200` will fold it at 200 characters. Is there a way to take the file and save first 50 but fold at 200 until it reaches the end of the row?

Here is a test of the test file.

```
PTSTISN1P AA1511200095PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP201506301200FPaaRPTSTISNB   PtstisPtstisPtstisOld Patients->Ins Ph #: '(888)888-8888' updated the phone number and called INS to let them know about the number changing. Also, updated number with hospital for Patients contacts.
```

I need it to save this part for each row it creates

```
PTSTISN1P AA1511200095PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
```

It is not saving all the P's as the first row has a few extra plus a date and time plus user that creates note and the second and remaining rows that info is not needed. Also, even better would be where `PTSTISN1P` change the 1 into 2 as that is needed for the second, third, etc. lines the 1 is for 1 second and 2 for all remaining lines.

I tried something like:

```
fold -50 note.txt > newnote.txt && fold -150 note.txt > newnote.txt
```

but that is not working like I thought it would.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the 50 characters? Do they go into the same output file? Somewhere else? Do you want to break the lines after the first 50 and then after every 200 characters? An example of the desired output for the given input line would be helpful.

Comment: How is this Powershell related?

Comment: @JohnØstergaardPetersen if it is easier to write something in powershell that would be fine as I have access to the server which has powershell on it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Here is what I would like it to look like.            PTSTISN1P AA1511200095PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP201506301200FPaaRPTSTISNB   PtstisPtstisPtstisOld Patients->Ins Ph #: '(888)888-8888' updated the phone number and called INS to let them know about the number changing. Also, updated number with hospital for Patients contacts.

Comment: Sorry pasted the wrong thing and wont let me edit it here it is.                         PTSTISN1P AA1511200095PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP201506301200FPaaRPTSTISNB   PtstisPtstisPtstisOld Patients->Ins Ph #: '(888)888-8888' updated th
PTSTISN2P AA1511200095PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPe phone number and called INS to let them know about the number changing. Also, updated number with hospital for Patients con
PTSTISN2P AA1511200095PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPtacts.

Comment: This example is just keeping the first 50 characters from each section of the notes. as the original one was not long enough example.

Comment: Please edit your question.